# need compatible motherboard

Tags: motherboard, compatibility

I can not seem to find a motherboard that is compatible with all my parts without going over $80. Here are my [parts](http://pcpartpicker.com/list/4pPL9W):

- Intel Core i5-2310 2.9GHz Quad-Core Processor
- Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- Kingston HyperX Fury 120GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- EVGA GeForce GTX 950 2GB Superclocked Video Card

I need a motherboard that supports the following:

- At least two sata 6/gbs connectors
- Support for ddr3 memory
- Socket 1155
- usb 3.0 front headers would also be preferred.
- Micro ATX Form Factor

If you know a motherboard that would work for me any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's an old CPU you have selected there (Sandy Bridge, 2011)

Comment: @SEJPM do you think you could recommend a processor?

Comment: You can't change the processor without invalidating answers, but as this is the lowest-end i5 from the Sandy Bridge series, something like the i5-6400, 6500 or maybe the i5-4440 should be the direct successors (always depends on the price though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tall order for a CPU from 2011. The Supermicro Motherboard MBD-C7Q67-O looks like it should fit the bill, however.  The only caveat is the front USB 3.0 headers (I took it as "you would like to have" rather than "required"), but those can be easily added with an add on card.

The full specifications can be found [here](http://bit.ly/2dr0Pjx).  As for the price, [Newegg](http://bit.ly/2dr0Pjx) and [Amazon](https://goo.gl/9kVMR9) both have it for more the $200, while you can get it for under $50 used/refurbished on [eBay](http://ebay.to/2e6drf1)

Answer (score 0):

This **[Intel DH77SL-50K](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-DH77SL-50K-LGA1155-Intel-Z77-Express-chipset-ATX-desktop-board-Bios-0097-/291871880254?hash=item43f4eb743e:g:iWwAAOSwiO9Xiofl)** ought to do it. Does everything you ask for and costs $50 on Ebay. Work for you?

Comment: i forgot to mention i have a micro atx sized case